# AJAX Response to JSON Data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON response, and the formatting is stumping me:

```
{
   "SearchResults": [
      {
         "SearchItem": "409885340",
         "Shipment": {
            "DRAvail": true,
            "ProNumber": "409885340",
            "PickupNumber": "24861628",
            "CustomerNumber": "688926",
            "BOLNumber": "100982156",
            "BOLReceived": true,
            "PODReceived": false,
```

And so on and so forth. Now when I return success in my AJAX (below):

```
success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        alert(JSON.parse(data.SearchResults[0]));
```

The alert data returns:

```
{"SearchResults":[{"SearchItem":"409885340","Shipment":{"DRAvail":true,"ProNumber":"409885340","PickupNumber":"24861628","CustomerNumber":"688926","BOLNumber":"100982156","BOLReceived":true,"PODReceived":false,"PONumber":"04272018"...
```

But on the next line (where it is parsed), it returns this in the console:

> TypeError: data.SearchResults is undefined

I know it's likely me being tired, but I'd appreciate any help in trying to get this to work...

Thanks

Comment: let searchResult = JSON.parse(data)
console.log(searchResult.SearchResults);

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax()` options and don't worry about manually parsing the response

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse first, the get then element you want:

```
//mind the closing parenthesis after data
alert(JSON.parse(data).SearchResults[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF your ajax response type is application/json you dont need to parse it

```
alert(data.SearchResults[0]);
```

will do

else

if return data is  string you need to parse it and than get value

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(parsedData.SearchResults[0]);
```

Comment: From the error message, I would assume that jQuery is not interpreting the response as JSON